# How to extract the first and last value from a data sequence based on a column value?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a time series dataset that can be created with the following code.

```
idx = pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=100, freq="H")
ts = pd.Series(idx)
dft = pd.DataFrame(ts,columns=["date"])
dft["data"] = ""

dft["data"][0:5]= "a"
dft["data"][5:15]= "b"
dft["data"][15:20]= "c"
dft["data"][20:30]= "d"
dft["data"][30:40]= "a"
dft["data"][40:70]= "c"
dft["data"][70:85]= "b"
dft["data"][85:len(dft)]= "c"
```

In the data column, the unique values are `a,b,c,d`. These values are repeating in a sequence in different time windows. **I want to capture the first and last value of that time window. How can I do that**?

Comment: I imagine you'll need `pandas.groupby` first and last, where you group by date

Comment: @iamwhoiam  : Provide an output .. it will be easier for other user to look at your need

Comment: @codeholic24 as you can see, there is an accepted solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute a grouper for your changing values using `shift` to compare consecutive rows, then use `groupby`+`agg` to get the min/max per group:

```
group = dft.data.ne(dft.data.shift()).cumsum()
dft.groupby(group)['date'].agg(['min', 'max'])
```

output:

```
                     min                 max
data                                        
1    2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 04:00:00
2    2018-01-01 05:00:00 2018-01-01 14:00:00
3    2018-01-01 15:00:00 2018-01-01 19:00:00
4    2018-01-01 20:00:00 2018-01-02 05:00:00
5    2018-01-02 06:00:00 2018-01-02 15:00:00
6    2018-01-02 16:00:00 2018-01-03 21:00:00
7    2018-01-03 22:00:00 2018-01-04 12:00:00
8    2018-01-04 13:00:00 2018-01-05 03:00:00
```

#### edit. combining with original data:

```
dft.groupby(group).agg({'data': 'first', 'date': ['min', 'max']})
```

output:

```
      data                date                    
     first                 min                 max
data                                              
1        a 2018-01-01 00:00:00 2018-01-01 04:00:00
2        b 2018-01-01 05:00:00 2018-01-01 14:00:00
3        c 2018-01-01 15:00:00 2018-01-01 19:00:00
4        d 2018-01-01 20:00:00 2018-01-02 05:00:00
5        a 2018-01-02 06:00:00 2018-01-02 15:00:00
6        c 2018-01-02 16:00:00 2018-01-03 21:00:00
7        b 2018-01-03 22:00:00 2018-01-04 12:00:00
8        c 2018-01-04 13:00:00 2018-01-05 03:00:00
```

Comment: This is almost right. but missing the original value of from the data column ( a-d )

Comment: You want to keep the original shape?

Comment: I want to keep the real values to the data column

Comment: @iamwhoiam have a look at the update, if this is not what you expect, please be explicit and provide an example of the expected output

Comment: The output shape is the first solution. Well in the first solution there are 8 values.  instead of int I am expecting real values. Then it will be the solution

Comment: I see, then you probably want `dft.groupby(group).agg({'data': 'first', 'date': ['min', 'max']})`